# how to resolve blocked by cors policy

Tags: node.js, angular

i am making the post request in my angular app an i am getting error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/products' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."
the fetch request is working correctly
the post request

```
  addProducts(
    name: string,
    price: number,
    imageUrl: string
  ): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, {
      name: name,
      price: price,
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
    });
  }
```

my backend server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const User = require("./users");
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );

  next();
});
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const dbURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/UsersDatabase";
mongoose.connect(dbURL, {
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
});
mongoose.connection.on("connected", function () {
  console.log("connected", dbURL);
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

app.post("/products", async (req, res) => {
  const productDetails = req.body.productDetails;
  await User.create(productDetails);
  res.status(200).json(productDetails);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware.

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```